# Why package.json is not copied to the next docker build stage?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I have a React.js application and a Node.js application which are in the same project in 2 separate directories. I build those in the same docker container and that works fine but it was rather taking a lot of time to build the production build of the react.js app so I applied multistaging in the dockerfile and that improved the performance greatly but even tough it is working, it does give me an error which I don't understand why is it happening.

So here is the dockerfile multistaging:

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS frontend

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./frontend/package.json ./frontend/
RUN npm install --prefix ./frontend/
# Copy the frontend source code
COPY ./frontend ./frontend/
# Build the frontend
RUN npm run build --prefix ./frontend/

FROM node:16-alpine AS backend
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
# Copy the backend package.json and install dependencies
COPY ./backend/package.json ./backend/
RUN npm install --prefix ./backend/
# Copy the backend source code
COPY ./backend ./backend/

FROM node:16-alpine AS final

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Set the environment variable for the backend
ARG DOCKER_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=${DOCKER_ENV}

RUN npm install -g serve

COPY --from=frontend /app/frontend/build ./frontend/build
COPY --from=backend /app/backend ./backend

# Create a start script
COPY start.sh /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/start.sh

# Start the backend and frontend
CMD ["/app/start.sh"]
```

Here is the output I get in the docker logs and that includes the error also - a missing package.json in the frontend folder which has the build stored there.

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/frontend/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-08T22_18_35_971Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: You are using an absolute path as the destination. Remove the `./`

Comment: The only part of the frontend you `COPY` into the final image is its `build` directory, not the `package.json` or any of the rest of the source.  What does the `start.sh` script do that needs `frontend/package.json`?